# Reading rds compressed file from git

Tags: r, git, gzip, rds

I am able to download rds file from git, but its giving error :

**Error in readRDS(temp) : embedded nul in string: 'name\0'**

```
url <- "https://github.com/filename.rds"
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(url,temp,method="libcurl",quiet=TRUE)
print(temp)
unzipped <- gzcon(con=gzfile(temp), level = 6, allowNonCompressed = TRUE, 
text = FALSE)
print(unzipped)
result <- readRDS(unzipped)
close(con)    
unlink(temp)
```

Comment: What if you try `download.file(url,temp,method="libcurl",quiet=TRUE, mode="wb")`. Are you sure you are using the right URL to the file contents and not the github HTML page for that file? I don't think the unzipping should be necessary with a standard rds file.

Comment: Why are you trying to uncompress an rds file?  The compression is _internal_.

Comment: If i don't uncompressed it, then also it throws same error, so I tried to read after uncompromising. its just a extra code, doesn't add any value.